# How to update Proget service at latest version?

Tags: proget

I am using ProGet free license at version 2.2.12 (build 5) and I would like to upgrade to the latest version 3.2.0.

I downloaded the .exe file from the official website and I tried to upgrade in a local virtual machine. After the installation, I launched the ProGet service at address localhost:8082.
The service started but it was very slow. When the page finally loads and I click on "activate license", the service no longer works. I restart the VM, but the web page at localhost:8082 remains unavailable.

Any idea what might be going wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by the service started and it was slow... slow at serving webpages? Slow to start up? You also shouldn't have to activate your license if you already have it installed, unless you're migrating to a different virtual machine.

Comment: Slow at serving webpages, and after the first start, the service are unreachable